# Execute function from child component on button click in parent component: Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, events, typescript, components

I have a following function inside a child component:

```
reload() {
    clearInterval(this.points);
    this.initiateInterval();
    this.redrawImages();
}
```

It's redrawing few images on `window.resize` event.

But in the parent component, I have a button `menu-burger` which shrunks the window. I want to bind to this button the `reload()` function from the child component.

This is my button from the parent component:

`<button class="collapseMenuIcon" (click)="toggleMenu()">`

I was looking for other questions about it on Stack, but in my case - this `reload` function uses a lot of stuff in this child component.

Also few solutions from other questions are deprecated, because Angular2 changes often.

Thank you in advance, I will upvote all answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shared Service is a very good option. Just to throw another option out there, depending on your use case, you can just use a Subject between the parent and child without the service, if you want.

Declare Subject in child:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

public static fireEvent: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

and subscribe in your constructor:

```
constructor(....) {
    MyChildComponent.fireEvent.subscribe(res => {
        this.reload();
    });
}
```

And in your parent:

```
import { MyChildComponent } from './my-path';
```

and on your button click, tell child to fire `reload`-method:

```
toggleMenu() {
  MyChildComponent.fireEvent.next(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to communicate between components. I personally use a service for that purpose, and it works great for me.

Read here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

The last example (the service one) is the one that I use, and is quite simple to implement.

Edit:

Using services allow you to have independent components, being able to use them in other parts of the app. You also can send/receive data and the communication is both sides. I strongly recommend this method.